# Is it safe to eat fish that has been left out in the cold overnight?

Tags: food-safety, fish

It's snowing over here, and we had made a fish delivery that we assumed had been canceled. (The fish store didn't answer their phone yesterday and most schools and businesses were closed.) However, it seems that the fish was left at our door late last night. It was probably there around 9 hours...? Normally I would toss it, but it's really cold out there and the fish is cool to the touch. I live in an apt building, so it was not actually outside in the snow, but the temperature in the hallway outside our front door is nearly as cold as outside. I have no way of measuring the temperature out there. Is it safe to eat...? How cold does it have to be to consider it safe? (And yes, we will complain to the store.)

Comment: Refrigeration temperatures are below 40F. Did your fish stay out at that or lower?

Comment: It's really impossible to say if it's safe or not without knowing what temperature it was held at.

Answer (score 0):

I hate throwing away food, for me (and I stress "for me") I would use the "Smell By" test and then make sure it is cooked really well through.  Make a stew, curry or pasta source (something where it is cooked through and in small bits). BUT DO NOT sushi, light pan fry or similar of it.

If you are in doubt do not use it, you do not want a dose of something a week before holidays.

Other factors
Was the fish cleaned?
Was it in bag or one of those polystyrene (Styrofoam) boxes?
Was it in ice?